# How can I convert a time difference in MillisecondsSinceEpoch back to minutes in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen that shows the percentage of a duration from start to finish. The start and end time was get from TimeOfDay and I have added the date to generate a DateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch integer.

Now I can find the time difference between the start and end by simple subtraction. How can I change the value I get to a minute to calculate the percentage. When I convert it back to date; the output is not the time difference, it is a new date.

```
  int trainingStartInEpoch = DateTime(trainingDateYear, trainingDateMonth, trainingDateDay, trainingStartHour, trainingStartMinutes).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  int trainingEndInEpoch = DateTime(trainingDateYear, trainingDateMonth, trainingDateDay, trainingEndHour, trainingEndMinutes).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  int timeDiff = trainingEndInEpoch - trainingStartInEpoch;
  final DateTime date2 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeDiff);

  print("epochDiff if posetive" " $timeDiff");
  print("difDate if posetive" " $date2");
```

Below is the output

epochDiff if posetive 14400000

difDate if posetive 1970-01-01 07:00:00.000

Comment: Clearly the time difference would not be a date (it would be a value in hours/minutes/seconds), so converting it to a DateTime makes no sense. There are 1000 milliseconds in a second, and 60 seconds in a minute, and 60 minutes in an hour, which is enough for you to use to work out the basic math involved in converting to minutes, and those minutes to hours, and if needed those hours to days.

Comment: So how can I do the above math. And the time difference in minutes is enough for my calculations

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `millisecondsSinceEpoch` at all.  Just subtract the two `DateTime` objects with `DateTime.difference` to get a `Duration` object, and then you can use `Duration.minutes`.

Comment: You can do `end.difference(start).inMinutes`, For TimeOfDay `late final diff = end.difference(start); late TimeOfDay time =TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(diff.inMilliseconds));`

Comment: As I said, it's basic math. Multiply the seconds per minute times the number of milliseconds (MS) in a second, and divide your millisecond value by that number : `Minutes = YourTimeInMS / (60 * 1000)`. I don't know Flutter/Dart, but it looks like @jamesdlin gave you a better solution for that platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be using the `.difference()` function in `DateTime`. For example:

```dart
final DateTime startTime = ...;
final DateTime endTime = ...;
final Duration duration = endTime.difference(startTime);

print("The duration is ${duration.inMinutes} minute(s)");
// duration.inMinutes
// duration.inSeconds
// duration.inDays etc.
```

You can get the total duration in minutes by using the `.inMinutes` attribute, you can also get the seconds, hours, days and etc.